# drupal_mail_system is returning empty object

Tags: 7, emails

I have installed mime module for sending html mails. Im receiving Drupal security update on my site but not sending/receiving any mails through my code.

```
$settings = array(
  'id' => $my_module . '_' . $my_mail_token,
  'to' => $email_to,
  'subject' => $email_subject,
  'body' => $email_message,
  'headers' => array(
    'From' => $conf['FROM_email'],
    'Sender' => $FROM,
    'Return-Path' => $FROM,
    'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed',
  ),
);


$system = drupal_mail_system($my_module, $my_mail_token);
if ($system->mail($settings)) {
  print 'success';
}
else {
  print 'failed';
}
```

I tried to `print_r($system)` which is supposed to return object of mail system interface but all I received was `HTMLMailSystem Object ( )`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call [`format`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/MailSystemInterface%3a%3aformat/7) method.

Try the following snippet:

```
$from = variable_get('system_mail', $my_email);
$message = array(
  'id' => $my_module . '_' . $my_mail_token,
  'to' => $my_email,
  'subject' => $message_subject,
  'body' => array($message_body),
  'headers' => array(
    'From' => $from,
    'Sender' => $from,
    'Return-Path' => $from,
  ),
);
$system = drupal_mail_system($my_module, $my_mail_token);

// The format function must be called before calling the mail function. 
$message = $system->format($message);

if ($system->mail($message)) {
  drupal_set_message('SUCCESS');
}
else {
  drupal_set_message('FAILURE');
}
```